# An excel file is hosted on Azure Blob, How do read it into a FileStream?

Tags: c#, excel, azure

I upload a file using c# to Azure Blob.
Now I want to read the uploaded file using ExcelDataReader.

I am using the below code.
where **_imageRootPathNos** is the path(http://imor.blob.core.windows.net/files) where the file is saved

```
FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(_imageRootPathNos + "/" + "ImEx.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I get an Error System.ArgumentException: 'URI formats are not supported.'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

ExcelDataReader can read data from any stream, not just a FileStream. You can use either WebClient (obsolete), HttpClient or Azure SDK to open a stream and read the blob.

Reading or downloading a blob opens and reads a stream anyway. Instead of eg. downloading the blob or reading all of its contents in a buffer, you access the stream directly. No matter which technique you use, in the end, you open a stream over a single URL for reading.

In your case, you can download and keep the file to reuse it, or you can read from the stream directly. You may want to do that in a web application if you don't have permissions to write to a disk file or if you server many requests at the same time and don't want to deal with temporary file storage.

Using HttpClient, you can use the [GetStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551738(v=vs.118).aspx) method to open a stream :

```
var client=new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://imor.blob.core.windows.net/files");
// Set headers and credentials
// ...
using(var stream=await client.GetStreamAsync("ImEx.xlsx"))
{
    var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    //Process the data
}
```

With the Azure SDK, you can use the [CloudBlob.OpenRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.openread.aspx) method:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Imex.xlsx");
using(var stream=await blob.OpenReadAsync())
{
    var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    //Process the data
}
```

You may want to store the data in a memory buffer or a file, eg for caching or reprocessing. To do that you can create a MemoryStream or FileStream respectively, and copy the data from the blob stream to the target stream.

With HttpClient, you can fill a memory buffer with :

```
//To avoid reallocations, create a buffer large enough to hold the file

using(var memStream=new MemoryStream(65536)) 
{
    using(var stream=await client.GetStreamAsync("ImEx.xlsx"))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
    }
    memStream.Position=0;
    var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memStream);
}
```

With the SDK:

```
using(var memStream=new MemoryStream(65536)) 
{
    //.....
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Imex.xlsx");
    await stream.DownloadToStreamAsync(memStream);
    memStream.Position=0;
    var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memStream);
    //...
}
```

To download a file you can replace the MemoryStream with a FileStream.

Comment: Great answer @Panagiotis. A lot more complete than mine

Comment: If one of the answers provided you a solution you should mark it as the answer

Comment: It's worth noting that  ExcelDataReader does not support reading hyperlinks.

Comment: @PaulHodgson that's not a problem at all. Downloading is not as simple as `HttpClient.GetXYZ`. What if the file is big? What if you need to resume? What if you want to perform concurrent downloads?

Comment: @PaulHodgson from the other side, a network stream is forward-only. What if you need to move back and forth in a file to read it? An Excel reader can't make the decision to either store everything in memory or write to an arbitrary temporary file

Comment: That's not quite what I meant.  There is no reader.GetHyperlink(x) function and using read.GetString(x) will return just the label of the hyperlink rather than the useful data.

Comment: I get: the error: `wrong local header signature 0x20333034`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access Azure Blob Storage files using a standard FileSteam.  As suggested in Chris's answer you could use the Azure SDK to access the file.  Alternatively you could use the [Azure Blob Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api).

Another solution would be to use [Azure File Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) and create a mapped network drive to the File storage.  Then you could use your code to access the file as if it were on a local or network storage system.

There are quite a number of technical differentiators between the two services. 
 As pricing goes, Azure File Storage is more expensive than Azure Blob Storage, however depending on the intended use, both are pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the Azure Storage service, it's recommended that you use the Azure .NET SDK. The SDK exposes the appropriate methods to download, upload and manage your containers and blob storage. In this case, your code should look like this:

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("files");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "imex.xlsx".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Imex.xlsx");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

You can find all the information you need on how to use the SDK here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

Comment: I'd suggest "would want" rather than "need" you could just use straight JSON and web api.  I would suggest using the SDK as it will help protect code from changes in the the Azure Storage API

Comment: The OP is trying to use ExcelDataReader which can read data from any stream, including one returned by HttpClient. Downloading isn't a good idea for web sites, web apps or serverless applications where writing to a temporary folder isn't practical due to permission or scalability reasons

Comment: In my defence, although I may be pedantic, he didn't mention that he was trying to implement this on a web app. However, I agree that using your proposed solution may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

I used this block of code to read the excel file(uploaded on azure) into Dataset

```
Uri blobUri = new Uri(_imageRootPath + "/" + fileName);
                var wc = new WebClient();
                var sourceStream = wc.DownloadData(blobUri);
                Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(sourceStream);
                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memoryStream);
                DataSet dsResult = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                return dsResult;
```

Comment: You already have a stream, why *copy* the data to another instead of reading directly from it?

Comment: ExcelReaderFactory needs a MemoryStream.

Comment: then it wouldn't work with FileStream. It needs a *stream*, not a specific type of stream